# How to addSubview with a position?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I have something like this:

```
myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
[mainCanvas addSubview: myViewController.view];
self.view = mainCanvas;
```

It will be added at the position (0, 0), but I want to add it at (0, 100) or somewhere else. How can I do so?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Something like this:

```
myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil];
myViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, myViewController.view.frame.size.width, myViewController.view.frame.size.height);  
[mainCanvas addSubview: myViewController.view];
self.view = mainCanvas;
```

Comment: @applefreak the frame *is* the position of the view in its superview's co-ordinate system. What you're asking for doesn't make sense.

Comment: This is the cleanest way and doesn't even require mask-translations to be enabled. Unbelievably, in my case, `(0, 0, width, height)` had to be declared explicitly as it wasn't default behaviour. Crazy!

Answer (score 12):

In addition to setting the `frame` property, you can also set the `center` property of a view.

Answer (score 8):

Set the frame property on the sub view.

Answer (score 7):

This is the best way I've found to add a subView, like a loading screen or something that you want to show whether you are in a `UIView`, `UIScrollView`, or `UITableView`.

```
myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyView" bundle:nil]; 
myViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:myViewController.view];
self.view.bounds = myViewController.view.bounds;
```

This will make the subView appear in full screen no matter where you are in the self.view by adding the subView to where you are currently located in your self.view instead of positioning it in the top left corner, only showing fully if you are at the very top of your view.